# Anthropomorphising operators should be closed as matters of opinion

Tags: discussion

Should Q&A's which ask whether matrix operators are human, and can go off and make their own assumptions, such as here:

[Is spectral leakage due to windowing 'different' for the DTFT and DFT?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/34211/is-spectral-leakage-due-to-windowing-different-for-the-dtft-and-dft)

be closed as a matter of religious opinion?

Comment: I would vote yes.  But as a participant, I'm biased, so will abstain.

Comment: Interesting discussion ;) I was really interested in the final answer(s), since this is the topic that one might argue about. Nonetheless I don't think that this question is primarily opinion based - we could definitely come up with a good answer. I could definitely clean up comments and move them to a chat.

Comment: As r-bj says in the comments, this is a religious question for many people. There have been extended flamewars on `comp.dsp` about it for decades. I doubt we can come up with an answer that satisfies all camps. Though, as usual @Matt L. has come up with a nice answer that seems to come down to brass tacks.

Comment: Let us not call it "religious", originally *religere* meant "to unite" instead of "to divide" :)